# HTTPS webservice using WCF

Tags: wcf

I try to connect to https web service over proxy at my end.

below is code snippet

```
    Dim strProxyURL As String = "http://myproxy.com"
    Dim mypingRequest As New pingRequest()
    Dim httpUri As New Uri("https://mysite.com")
    Dim mybinding As New WSHttpBinding()
    Dim remoteAddress As New EndpointAddress(httpUri)

    mybinding.UseDefaultWebProxy = True

    mybinding.BypassProxyOnLocal = True


    mybinding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Windows

    mybinding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Mtom
    mybinding.TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
    mybinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential 'TransportWithMessageCredential

    mybinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows

    Dim myMBClient As New v1_PortTypeClient(mybinding, remoteAddress)

    myMBClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "username"
    myMBClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "pwd"

    myMBClient.ping()
```

when I use proxy I error proxy authentication required error
if I remove proxy from desktop and use direct internet then I go to site web service but cannot login even thought the gave correct username and password

Comment: issue is resolved. WCF web services uses Custom binding hence error. also i have add webrequest.defaultwebproxy and credentials to access via web proxy at requesting client side                                 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187001/wcf-custom-http-proxy-authentication

Answer (score 0):

issue is resolved. WCF web services uses Custom binding hence error. also i have add webrequest.defaultwebproxy and credentials to access via web proxy at requesting client side                                 [WCF Custom Http Proxy Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187001/wcf-custom-http-proxy-authentication)