# How to set credentials for HTTP Proxy in WCF Client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, proxy, credentials

I'm looking for the way to provide credentials (grammatically) for HTTP proxy that should be used to connect to service (Security Token Service), the proxy credentials differ from the credentials for the service.

I saw several posts here (it took me back to 2006-8) and the solution was by changing the default proxy

```
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("http://myproxyserver",true);
proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = proxy;
```

I think it is risky to change the global setting for all WebRequests from my assembly that performs a dedicated task.

I'm wondering if in .NET 4.5 there is a better solution for this case.

Similar questions:

[WCF Custom Http Proxy Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187001/wcf-custom-http-proxy-authentication)

[How can I set an HTTP Proxy (WebProxy) on a WCF client-side Service proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951523/how-can-i-set-an-http-proxy-webproxy-on-a-wcf-client-side-service-proxy)

Answer (score 0):

Don't set default proxy, set [proxy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.proxy(v=vs.110).aspx) object with desired credentials per request

Comment: I can set proxy via WSHttpBinding, but there is no way to set credentials.

Comment: Would WSHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType help?

Comment: No, because it only has Credential Type but not the credentials itself. It assumes (as I understand and as I read through similar questions) that proxy credentials and client credentials are the same. That is not my case.