# MetadataExchangeClient using Web Proxy

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I am trying to connect to a URI pointing to a WSDL file which describes a WCF service by using the MetadataExchangeClient class.

```
var mexClient = new MetadataExchangeClient(uri, MetadataExchangeClientMode.HttpGet);
var metaDocs = mexClient.GetMetadata();
```

The problem is that I cannot access this uri directly and need to go through a HTTP proxy server.
The proxy server URL can change at runtime so I cannot simply configure it through the app.config file.

Where can I specify the proxy server information in the MetadataExchangeClient class?

Anyone got an idea? WCF experts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the proxy in the `app.config` like this:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="true">
   <proxy bypassonlocal="true"
          proxyaddress="http://proxy.domain.org:8888/" />
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that proxy data (url, credentials) is configured at runtime. So I cannot hardcode it in `app.config`. (I updated the question).

Comment: Could you include that code in question? Do you do it like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186800/is-it-possible-to-specify-proxy-credentials-in-your-web-config)

Comment: In my application the user can configure a proxy at runtime. Based on that, I have to disable the default proxy and use the newly specified proxy settings. I have to pick up these new settings immediately. Restarting the application is not an option.

Comment: Do you update the system proxy when the user updates the proxy? How do you set the proxy?

Comment: No, the system proxy is not updated. The system proxy is the default, but the user can specify a custom proxy, which is just valid for the application.

Comment: Do you use something like this: [click here!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186800/is-it-possible-to-specify-proxy-credentials-in-your-web-config) to update the proxy?

Comment: Thx, you posted that URL before. But how does that handle the switch from system proxy to the "manually" configured one?

Comment: You can let `IsBypassed` return `false` or `true`.

Comment: Give me some time to try that out. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the GetChannelFactory and provide an implementation that can create a suitable endpoint i.e. a BasicHtppBinding with the proxy details added.

See here for a clue to how programmatically set Binding.

- [How can I set an HTTP Proxy (WebProxy) on a WCF client-side Service proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951523/how-can-i-set-an-http-proxy-webproxy-on-a-wcf-client-side-service-proxy)

See here for starting point on creating the Channel Factory (see the 3 comments at the end of the post)

- http://msdn.itags.org/visual-studio/83755/

This shows how to use MetadataExchangeClient with a Custom Binding:

- http://wikiencyclopedia.net/WCF/3.5.30729.1/untmp/Orcas/SP/ndp/cdf/src/WCF/infocard/Service/managed/Microsoft/InfoCards/InfoCardMetadataExchangeClient.cs/2/InfoCardMetadataExchangeClient.cs

Here's the .NET Framework Source to MetadataExchangeClient so you can get a better understanding of what it is doing.

- http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/WCF/WCF/3@5@30729@1/untmp/Orcas/SP/ndp/cdf/src/WCF/ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Description/MetadataExchangeClient@cs/1/MetadataExchangeClient@cs