# Setting proxy authentication on service reference through Svcutil.exe

Tags: .net, wcf, svcutil.exe

as the title suggests, i'd like to set my proxy authentication credentials when creating a proxy service through svcutil.exe. As you know when adding the service reference through VS2010 (Add Service Reference) we can't set proxy credential.

I read on some blogs that this would be possible by creating the proxy service directly through svcutil.exe, since VS2010 uses it anyway. I tried to create the service on it, but it wasn't possible. Even creating through svcutil i still got the Proxy Authentication Required error. I also tried modifying the svcutil.exe.config with `<proxy usesystemdefault="True" bypassonlocal="True"/>` but i didn't work either.

Reading [here](http://kjellsj.blogspot.com.br/2008/07/wcf-svcutil-proxy-problems.html) i tried to set on my app web.config the following:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" >
      <proxy usesystemdefault="True" proxyaddress="http://xxxxx:****" bypassonlocal="True"/>
      <bypasslist>
        <add address=".+\.xxxx\.com:\d{1,5}" />
      </bypasslist>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

And create the service, but once again the error persisted. I'm getting a little short of option since i already tried everything i know.

**QUESTION**

So, do you know how to set the proxy authentication credentials when creating a service proxy?

Comment: This could be duplicate of [SO: How can I set an HTTP Proxy (WebProxy) on a WCF client-side Service proxy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951523/how-can-i-set-an-http-proxy-webproxy-on-a-wcf-client-side-service-proxy)

Comment: It would be if i could create the client-side classes generated with svcutil.exe. However as i need to setup my proxy authentication here, where i work, i can't even create the cliente-side classes because svcutil fails.

Comment: I struggled with a very similar problem today. If you're interested, you can see my solution in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124350/how-to-run-svcutil-exe-from-behind-authenticating-proxy