# How to set different credentials of c# wcf client for proxy and service endpoint?

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, http-proxy

Can somebody tell me how, in a generated wcf client, to set separate credentials for the network proxy and the actual service endpoint? So I have a simlar situation as in [How to set proxy credentials to specific wcf client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968307/how-to-set-proxy-credentials-to-specific-wcf-client), but I need to authenticate differently to the proxy than to the web service endpoint:

```
var b = client.Endpoint.Binding as BasicHttpBinding;
/// [...]
b.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
b.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic; // !!!
b.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Basic; // !!!

client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = login;
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;
```

So where to put my `proxyLogin` and `proxyPassword`? Any ideas?

Comment: It's insane that WCF does not support this.