# Working with WSTrustChannelFactory and web proxy settings

Tags: c#, security, proxy, wif, ws-trust

in WSTrustChannelFactory documentation there is a reference to working with proxy:

```
  One common pattern where the OnBehalfOf feature is used is the proxy 
  pattern where the client cannot access the STS directly but instead 
  communicates through a proxy gateway
```

I can't seem to find an example.
In some of my users' computers a proxy is defined for exteral request.
How can I request the token if the STS is behind proxy.

Currently I am getting it as follows:

```
var rst = new RequestSecurityToken{...}
IWSTrustChannelContract wsTrustChannelContract = factory.CreateChannel();
var token = wsTrustChannelContract.Issue(rst) as GenericXmlSecurityToken;
```

How can I change it to using the proxy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OnBehalfOf is for situations where you build the proxy yourself - like the ADFS proxy. 
I haven't seen any sample for that either - but it follows the same pattern as ActAs.

It has nothing to do with "regular" web proxies that might be between you and your STS.

But have a look here:
[How can I set an HTTP Proxy (WebProxy) on a WCF client-side Service proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951523/how-can-i-set-an-http-proxy-webproxy-on-a-wcf-client-side-service-proxy)