# Set Proxy Server for WCF in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, wcf, proxy

Sorry if this has been raised elsewhere...

I am trying to consume a WCF service in vb.net. The application that is consuming the service sits behind a proxy server, and so needs to connect to the proxy server to get to the service.

In old school web references, this was easy to do with a couple of lines of code to set the proxy server for the web request.

Is there an equivalent way of doing it now? Preferably in such a way that the proxy address can be changed through configuration used in the application rather than amending app.config files.

Comment: Yes.  Take a look at this [question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951523/745969).

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!