# Powershell to execute WCF service with Proxy

Tags: powershell, wcf, wsdl, proxy-server, webproxy

I am trying to execute a WCF service / WSDL using Powershell, and I found I can use "New-WebServiceProxy" cmdlet to do the job.

Unfortunately it appears that if I execute directly on my environment, it will not work because it is blocked by our Proxy Server, then I found Net.WebProxy cmdlet which can glue them together.

But, I am not too familiar with the 2 cmdlet, how do I use New-WebServiceProxy but at the same time defining Proxy just like in Net.WebProxy?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See if this discussion and answers resolves your use case.

[How can I set an HTTP Proxy (WebProxy) on a WCF client-side Service proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951523/how-can-i-set-an-http-proxy-webproxy-on-a-wcf-client-side-service-proxy)

As for this...

```
But, I am not too familiar with the 2 cmdlet, how do I use New-WebServiceProxy but at the same time defining Proxy just like in Net.WebProxy?
```

Are you looking for what is the difference between the two?

One is  a built-in cmdlet defined to be used in a specific way and the other is not. There is no such MS provided cmdlet called, Net.WebProxy.

```
(Get-Command -Name *web*) -match 'proxy' | Format-Table -AutoSize

CommandType Name                Version Source                         
----------- ----                ------- ------                         
Cmdlet      New-WebServiceProxy 3.1.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
```

That is a raw Windows .Net class...

See these resources:

[Web​Proxy  Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webproxy?view=netframework-4.7.2)
Definition
Namespace: System.Net   Assemblies:System.dll, netstandard.dll, System.Net.WebProxy.dll

[Web​Proxy  Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webproxy.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2)
Definition
Namespace: System.Net   Assemblies:System.dll, netstandard.dll, System.Net.WebProxy.dll

... that you can leverage in PowerShell modules / scripts.