# Sending username and password in a webservice call

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I have created a wbservice. In the webservice I have created a method to send an acknowledgement. For sending the acknowledgement I have provided the link of the url in my web.config file as below:-

```
<applicationSettings>
 <ABCD.Properties.Settings>
 <setting name="Servicename"
serializeAs="String">
  <value>http://10.237.1.1/X/Y/Z</value>
 </setting>
  </ABCD.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

But when I am running my webservice then I am getting the error as:- The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized. 
Is it that I have to provide the username and password while sending the acknowledgement. If yes then please tell me how is it possible?

Comment: What type of Web Service you created? What is Web Service configuration?

Comment: The webservice is developed in .Net4.0 configuration

Comment: I meant if it is WCF service, Web API service or ASMX service? And what configuration is in your Web.config/App.config of Web Service?

Comment: It is a WCF webservice. And the target framework is 4.0 in the Web.Config. I am not getting exactly what you want in the Web.config?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105499/how-to-set-proxy-with-credentials-to-generated-wcf-client

Comment: You have to read about how to configure WCF services first: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733932.aspx and then how to configure WCF clients: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735103.aspx

Answer (score 0):

if the service is hosted in IIS, you may have set authentication on, if so, you'll need to have your client send credentials depending on your authentication type.  if you didn't intend to set authentication up, set it to allow anonymous access